# How do I create a data structure that will be serialized this JSON format in python?

Tags: python, django, json, list, dictionary

I have a function that accepts a list of date objects and should output the following dictionary in JSON:

```
    {
   "2010":{
      "1":{
         "id":1,
         "title":"foo",
         "postContent":"bar"
      },
      "7":{
         "id":2,
         "title":"foo again",
         "postContent":"bar baz boo"
      }
   },
   "2009":{
      "6":{
         "id":3,
         "title":"foo",
         "postContent":"bar"
      },
      "8":{
         "id":4,
         "title":"foo again",
         "postContent":"bar baz boo"
      }
   }
}
```

Basically I would like to access my objects by year and month number.
What code can convert a list to this format in python that can be serialized to the dictionary above in json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

d = defaultdict(dict)
for date in dates:
    d[date.year][date.month] = info_for_date(date)
json.dumps(d)
```

Where info_for_date is a function that returns a dict like those in your question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.
But it's still not accurate enough, in one month I may have more then one object. Should this dictionary contain lists as their final values? How would that be serialized to json?

Comment: @the_drow, you could use a `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`.  Then, do `d[date.year][date.month].append(info_for_date(date))`.  That means each month will eventually hold a JSON array (of one or more JSON objects).